# Why are the Pololu AVR programmer and Microchip Studio showing different target voltages with the same PCB?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, pcb, microchip, programmer

Yesterday I programmed a PCB (powering it using an external power supply, it's a PCB of a commercial device) with an ATMEGA2560 MCU using the Pololu AVR v2.1 programmer and the Microchip Studio application. There is a 6-pin ISP header on the PCB that is used to program the MCU. I saw in the documentation of the Pololu AVR v2.1 progammer that there is an auto voltage detection feature, which I left as default in auto mode.

When I connected it to Microchip Studio it showed a target voltage of 3.7V. There were no issues and I programmed the MCU successfully. Today I tried to do the same thing but the target voltage in Microchip Studio now shows 4.8V. I was able to program the MCU successfully and again there were no issues.

Why so? Where does this difference in voltages come from? I'm specifically interested in why I was able to program the MCU at both voltages. Is it because the Pololu AVR programmer is measuring the wrong voltages, but there are no issues when trying to program/dump the ATMEGA2560 MCU because it runs on both voltages?

Comment: What voltage were you powering the board at? What voltage appears on the V+ pin of the ISP port?

Comment: @Colorado.Rob - I didn't check the V+ pin on the ISP port, but the board should work at 5V. I'm trying to figure out why I was able to program the MCU at these different voltages and what actually happened. Should this specific ATMEGA2560 MCU work at both voltages and be able to be programmed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the ATMEGA2560 can be programmed from 1.8V to 5V. It has been a while since I looked at the voltage/MHz graph of the Atmega. The programmer may be able to detect the voltage if present, otherwise it may supply V+ itself. That's why I'm curious what voltage is present on V+.

Comment: @Colorado.Rob - The Pololu AVR programmer's output voltage is disabled by default, so it can only detect the voltage. I guess only the ATMEGA2560V can be programmed at 1.8V, not the ATMEGA2560 (no V)? If I understand correctly, even though the voltage was different, there shouldn't be a problem programming that particular ATMEGA2560?